# Why return-type 'cv' is ignored?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, language-lawyer, return-type

At least in 'Clang' & 'GCC'. Here is an example:

```
char *const InString(char *const p) {

    return gets(p);
}

int main()
{
    static char arr[260];

    char * &&str = InString(arr); //compiles without error - what??????
}
```

As most of you probably knows in the second line of '`main'` we are bounding the return-value temporary ('prvalue') into an **'rvalue reference'**  thus extending its life time. So my question is what is happening here - is 'cv' for return-values really ignored and if so where in the standard this is written or else how `'char *const &&'` is converted to `'char * &&'`?

*Need ISO C++ standard qualification.

EDIT: The thing is that before 'C++ 11' you weren't allowed to modify the return-value whatsoever because 'rvalues' weren't introduced and also because something like:

```
InString(arr) = nullptr;
```

Was meaningless. However now you can extend the 'return-value' life-time and so modifying it becomes possible:

```
auto &&refRetVal = InString(arr);

refRetVal = nullptr;
```

From this it comes that the 'const' return 'cv' can be useful. If the return-type of 'InString' above is 'constant' then the second assignment to 'nullptr' will be illegal.

Comment: The _cv-qualifier_ in return types is ignored only of the very first level, so `int const foo()` equals `int foo()` but `int const &foo()` does not equal `int &foo()`. Besides that, I'm not sure what you are asking...

Comment: I'm asking about the return-value temporary 'prvalue' which life-time, starting with C++11, can be extended and thus modifying it became useful and so the 'const' cv.

Comment: @FISOCPP: It was _always_ possible to modify a temporary through an rvalue expression (though I concede there were one or two very minor restrictions). That is not new in C++11. It's just that, in your example, you'd have had to fiddle with `const_cast` or invoke a `mutable` member function to do it, because, you could only have bound the temporary to a `const` ref in the first place. However, if you consider a simple example like `std::cout << (std::stringstream() << 123).rdbuf();` then it becomes clearer.

Comment: "before 'C++ 11' you weren't allowed to modify the return-value whatsoever because 'rvalues' weren't introduced"  - complete rubbish, C++ has always had rvalues, and you could always modify the return value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After considering the quote mentioned by @dyp, which is [expr]/6:

> If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`,” where `T` is a
>   cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, **the type of
>        the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis**.

The conclusion is rather simple: As the expression `InString(..)` is a prvalue, the type of `InString(..)` (which is the initializer of the reference) is simply adjusted to `char*`, which is clearly reference compatible to the target type of the reference (also `char*`). In other words, the `const` you added is simply ignored when determining the **type of the function call expression** (but it is **not** ignored when looking at the **function type** itself!).

However, for scalar prvalues, references never bind *directly* to the initializer expression, but a temporary is initialized and the reference bound to it:

```
int&& i = 4; // Temporary initialized with 4 and bound to i

int const f();
int&& ref = f(); // Initializer expression has type int - same as above
```

Comment: Ah, yes, true. I didn't get this from the other answers. This one definitely explains it the best.

Comment: And this is indeed one of the weirdest rules I've encountered in C++. I think I've learned it when trying to bind to an lvalue reference where the type is deduced: `auto& x = g();` doesn't work if `g` returns a const non-class type.

Comment: @dyp By now I feel like one could write a short book about rules of reference initialization. It gets more complicated each time I try to provide analyses. (Btw: Thanks for correcting me. :o))

Comment: Probably, the reason is that prvalues of non-class non-array type are immutable - they're values, not objects. Even if we try to bind them to rvalue refs, they're not directly bound, but an object which is initialized with them. Methinks prvalues of non-class non-array types are treated as true *values*, not *objects*.

Comment: Yes, the whole initialization topic is rather complicated. Recently, I've argued that *function lvalues* appear in ref init because there are no rvalues of function type. It sometimes seems like a gathering of obscure parts of the language.

Comment: @dyp So you're saying there is no fundamental difference between an integer literal and a constant expression prvalue of integral type? (Apart from the funny fact that the latter is not allowed as a null-initializer for pointers)

Comment: (Because an integer literal is IMO the best example for pure "valueness" in C++.)

Comment: @dyp Well, the term "value" doesn't really apply to functions, so it's IMO nonsensical to talk about lvalues of function type. You can't put a function on the left-hand side of an assignment, IIRC

Comment: Hmm. They're different kinds of expressions, for example (grammatically). For class types and arrays, we need to be able to get pointers, so they cannot be values to the same degree that *the other types* can.

Comment: @M.M Thanks, that was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The *cv-qualifier* in return types is ignored only of the very first level, so `int const foo()` equals `int foo()` but `int const &foo()` does not equal `int &foo()`.

In your case, your function `char *const InString()` is equivalent to `char *InString()`.

And about the binding of the `char *&&str = InString(arr)`. The return of the function is a r-value (a temporary), and `str` is an r-value reference, so this is expected. Of course, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the scope of the reference.

BTW, your code, compiled with `-Wextra` gives in CLang++:

> warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect [-Wignored-qualifiers]

And in G++:

> warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]

Comment: Standard paper qualification is what I need.

Comment: @FISOCPP: I think you mean "C++ standard citation/quotation".

Comment: There are generally no expressions of const non-class non-array type. `const` is not ignored on the return type. Check with class types.

Comment: *"There are generally no expressions of const non-class non-array type"* Sorry, I have to qualify that: there are no *prvalue* expressions of non-const, non-array type.